# Copy (or reference) just the argument of a function in Excel)

Tags: excel, function, arguments

I'd like to apply a new function to the same set of cells referenced in a previously used function. For instance, in my specific case, cell J73 contains the single function:

`=SUM(G68:G73,G64:G66,G62,G59:G60,G55:G57,G48:G53,G46,G36:G38,G40:G44)`

and I would like to use the COUNT function on the same set of cells without individually selecting them again, in order to display how many values went into the result of the SUM function. In other words, I would like to end up with cell K74 containing:

`=COUNT(G68:G73,G64:G66,G62,G59:G60,G55:G57,G48:G53,G46,G36:G38,G40:G44)`

I also will have to do this >150 times with varying sets and numbers of cells, so copying and pasting the arguments by hand would also be highly time consuming. It seems like there must be a general way to reference the argument of one function in another, but it is proving very hard to search for.

Edit: To be clear, in my particular case, all of the cells like J73 above (sums of multiple series of data) are already present in my sheet (so using fixed references would have been useful if I had originally included them, but are not especially useful now). In my ideal world, there would be a simple formula that pulls just the argument out of the first set of cells so I can quickly create a new column that shows how many pieces of information went into each of the cells using the SUM function. Unfortunately, this doesn't exactly appear to be the case, but it looks like there may be several promising work-arounds.

Comment: So the cells referenced remain constant but just the function changes?  if so then use fixed references by placing a $ in front of the row and column references `=sum($G$68:$G$73, $G$64:$G$66)` then copy and paste and change the function. but this assumes you're cells referenced remain constant.  Do they?

Comment: You could make a custom function in VBA and get the formula of a cell using `.Formula` and parse out the referenced cells that way.

Comment: What jumps into my mind is the possibility of storing the list of cell addresses in one cell and referring to that from other formulae. e.g. If A1 contains `G68:G73` then `=sum(indirect(A1))`and `=count(indirect(A1))` work. Unfortunately that use of `indirect` does not extend to the case where A1 needs to contain multiple ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pnuts got it right when he commented that you should redesign your sheet.  I can think of two situations where you would need multiple, non-contiguous ranges: Subtotals and extraneous data.

**Subtotals**

If you're skipping some rows because they contain subtotals, then you need to use the SUBTOTAL function instead of SUM and COUNT. With SUBTOTAL, you can aggregate the numbers over the entire range but skip any SUBTOTAL functions within that range.

If you've never used SUBTOTAL before, here's an example.  Type 1 and 2 in A1 and A2 respectively. In A3, type

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,A1:A2)
```

and you'll get 3.  Then type 10 and 20 in A5 and A6 respectively. Copy the formula From A3 to A7 to get 30.  Now the magic.  In cell A10, type

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,A1:A9)
```

and you'll get 33.  It only counts the cells that don't already contain a SUBTOTAL formula.

**Extraneous information**

This is a little tougher because each situation is different, but if you're skipping rows because there's irrelevant data in the mix and you can't rearrange the data, then you should consider using SUMPRODUCT and some helper columns.  You might, for instance, add a helper column at column A and put an "x" in every row that you want to sum in column G. Then use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A40="x")*(G1:G40))
```

To count, simply

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A40="x"))
```

Comment: Trust me, I would love to redesign spreadsheet, but it's just not feasible currently. I think the SUMPRODUCT method might work though (it's not exactly extraneous information in the cells I'm skipping, it's just a different category I need to separate out for this particular analysis). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Taking up chancea's suggestion, if you are able to use access and use VBA then the following user defined function called `COUNTINSUM` should get you what you want

```
Function COUNTINSUM(X As Range) As Variant
    COUNTINSUM = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    If X.Count <> 1 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Left(X.Formula, 5) = "=SUM(" Then
        COUNTINSUM = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Mid(X.Formula, 6, Len(X.Formula) - 6)))
    End If
End Function
```

Once you have added this to your workbook, it can be used on the worksheet just like any other function. It takes just one argument, this being a reference to a cell containing a `SUM()` formula. So if `J73` contains

```
=SUM(G68:G73,G64:G66,G62,G59:G60,G55:G57,G48:G53,G46,G36:G38,G40:G44)
```

and you want `J74` to contain the number of values making up this sum then enter `=COUNTINSUM(J73)` in cell `J74`.

`COUNTINSUM` will return `#VALUE!` in all cases except when its argument (the thing in brackets) is a single cell and that cell contains just a `SUM` formula. Just like the `COUNT` function if there are any zero values forming part of your SUM, COUNTINSUM will count these in its result. It is not entirely foolproof, if you are in the habit of putting spaces immediately before or after the `=` sign when entering your `SUM` formula, it will return `#VALUE!` instead of what  you want.

Creating a user defined function like this can be a bit of a last resort and I agree with other suggestions that a worksheet re-design might be a more appropriate solution depending on why  you are skipping cells in your summations.

Comment: Thanks for this, it sounds like it would do exactly what I am looking for. Can you elaborate on why it might be better as a last resort though? Should I be worried about instability or other problems?